# Who are the missionaries and godly men who were helped by Keswick Theology for a fuller Christ like life and ministry?

Tags: missionary

My curiosity arises from two sources.

[J I Packer ( Reformed Theology ) says the Keswick Theology ruined him](https://www.thegospelcoalition.org/blogs/kevin-deyoung/pietistic-goofiness-how-keswick-theology-nearly-destroyed-j-i-packer/)

Whereas

[T Austin Sparks says that the Keswick Theology helped him lead a fuller life](https://www.austin-sparks.net/about.html)

Since reformed theologians are against Keswick Theology, I would like to get a list of missionaries and godly men who were helped by Keswick Theology for a fuller Christ-like life and ministry so that I can study their lives.

Comment: "Columbia Bible College and Seminary (now Columbia International University) was founded by one of the early leaders of the American Keswick movement, Robert C. McQuilkin. His son, Robertson McQuilkin, contributed the Keswick chapter to the book "Five Views of Sanctification."  Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher_Life_movement  This article is about CIU: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Columbia_International_University

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people I came to know are [Hudson Taylor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hudson_Taylor), [Amy Carmichael](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amy_Carmichael), [Oswald Chambers](https://utmost.org/oswald-chambers-bio/) & [Billy Graham](https://billygraham.org/about/biographies/billy-graham/).

Source: [What is the Keswick movement, and is it biblical?](https://www.gotquestions.org/Keswick-movement.html)

This [letter of Hudson Taylor](https://www.wholesomewords.org/missions/biotaylor11.html) tells us how he experienced the second blessing.